# Different behaviours in the same function based on trait properties until specialization is stabilized?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, explicit-specialization

I have the following problem.

I want to write a generic function that process some geometry. The geometry may, or may not have normals. If it has defined normals, it should use one set of functionality if it does not, it should use another. For both cases the output would be identical (up to numerical differences of course).

I am trying to implement such functionality, options seem to be:

- Implement one common functionality in one function, then implement 2 wrapping functions, one for each case. I don't like this one because I have lot's of generics, it will make integrating this functionality a nightmare as all things depending on it will need to have 2 implementations.
- Use specialization, as of now, it is not stabilized.
- Make a trait and have it return a dummy boolean just to check which of the two cases is the current one.
- This is small but unecessary runtime overhead, and demands types created by the user implement the trait, which is inconvenient.

Is there some work around to get a single function to switch behaviours while not forcing the user to care explicitly about it?

Comment: 2 types, 1 with 1 without normals, implement the differing behaviour in a trait that both implement, have the function call that method when it wants to do either a or b.

Comment: The types are quite complicated, this would lead to a lot of non trivial duplicated code.

Comment: Uhm, compose the type into bits that you can reuse. Maybe just a wrapper that implemnts barely more than behaviour a or b.

Comment: Something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=91b3ac1bac8d01c614c23826ae455c72)

Comment: You will have to implement a trait anyway, even with specialization, no? Then what's the problem with the "function returning `bool`" approach? You can make it an associated const to make sure no runtime overhead is involved.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want precisely. Could you illustrate that with some dummy code ?